# How to set username in Firebase auth

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase-authentication

Hello how can I set username on Signup for Firebase User. I use firebase Authentication API. I thought about try / catch block and setting User properties like

```
const user = auth.currentUser;
user.name = 'John123'
```

Is it possible?

```
const onSubmitHandler = (e: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
        
        
    }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Firebase Authentication has a display name for each user, which can be whatever you want it to be. To set it, call `updateProfile` as shown in the documentation on [updating the user's profile](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#update_a_users_profile):

```
await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password);
updateProfile(auth.currentUser, {
  displayName: "John123"
})
```

Comment: Yes it works. Thank you sir. At the beginning I thought it is not connected with registration but it can be connected. Thank you once again.

Answer (score 2):

```
   const result = await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
    auth,
    email,
    password
  );

  await updateProfile(result.user, {
    displayName: username,
  });
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, including an explanation really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

It is full solution

```
 const onSubmitHandler = (e: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        const createUser = async ( ) => {
            await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
            updateProfile(auth.currentUser!, {
            displayName: "John123" // it can be a value of an input
          })
        }
        createUser()
    }
```